# Have a electron window not affected by WM's

Tags: javascript, electron

Currently with my BSP based WM electron window resizes to accommodate the screen, according to browserWindow [options](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) `focusable` tag should prevent it, bug when I tap on my app, the window isn't focused and doesn't listen for inputs.

What other flag would me have my window not affected by BSP based WM 
My current flags for `browserWindow` with gets affected by WMs

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 650,
      height: 400,
      center: true,
      frame: false,
      resizable:false,
      alwaysOnTop: true,

      webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
      }
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "BSP" and "WM"?

Comment: BSP means [Binary Space Parition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) and WM is a windows manager. A window manager which divides windows in equal part to use all space in screen

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to [bspwm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bspwm) specifically, is that the case? (Because BSPs are an _abstract_ concept in computer-science, I usually only see them in reference to 3D scene representations, like in game engines (Quake, etc)) - not window managers.

Comment: Although in my case [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) many other WM's use BSP based arranging

Comment: There's a difference in "stop interacting with the WM" (as stated in the docs which *applies to Linux only*) and not obeying the size constraints of the WM in the first place (that's gonna be hard because WMs are actually tasked to *manage* the desktop space and *not hand off* this management to client applications). But I'm a little confused: Please clarify what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to have your window always stay at 650x400?

Comment: 1) Have it stay at `650x400` (I can use resizable option)
2) But have it movable by the user and not wm, the focusable flags says it does it, but then I am not able to interact with window at all